# csvsimple - import only certain columns

Tags: tables, optional-arguments, csv, csvsimple, options

```
\begin{figure}
\csvautobooktabular[]{csvs/some-ttests.csv}
\end{figure}
```

This produces way too large a table (cut off on the left side), so I want to split it up into multiple tabulars, one for columns `1,3,4`, one for columns `1,6,7`, one for columns `1,9,10`, etc., where the first column always contains the information about what is stored in the rows and the other two are the actual data.

How do I limit the columns printed by csvsimple to a selection, say `1,3,4`, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csvsimple` allows you to choose which columns of your `.csv` are to print, just put only the column name `\csvcol...` you need in the command list or your `\csvreader` macro.

In the following MWE `filecontents` package and environment are used only to create the file `some-ttests.csv`. Of course, you don't need them in your actual document, since you've already got the file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\csvstyle{mystyle}{
    tabular=ccc,
    table head=\toprule,
    table foot=\bottomrule,
    no head,
    late after line=\\,
    late after first line=\\\midrule,
    }

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{some-ttests.csv}
one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
3,6,5,5,2,3,4,5,3,1
2,5,7,1,6,5,3,9,5,1
7,3,0,5,5,2,0,8,4,4
\end{filecontents*}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Table with comuns 1, 3 and 4\label{tab134}}
\csvreader[mystyle]{some-ttests.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Table with comuns 1, 6 and 7\label{tab167}}
\csvreader[mystyle]{some-ttests.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Table with comuns 1, 9 and 10\label{tab1910}}
\csvreader[mystyle]{some-ttests.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolix & \csvcolx}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Complete table for comparison\label{tabtot}}
\csvreader[
    tabular=*{10}{c},
    table head=\toprule,
    table foot=\bottomrule,
    no head,
    late after line=\\,
    late after first line=\\\midrule, ]{some-ttests.csv}{}{\csvlinetotablerow}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the answer. A tiny bit too late for me, but the next person having this question will find this very useful.

Comment: @User1291 Thank you! I was searching for old questions to be answered :)